# Ruby model stores controller values in MYSQL with added characters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller method that looks like this below. However, the `schedule = params[:message][:schedule]` takes an input like this `["","2"]` and is stored as a string in the database that is MySQL.

When `Schedule.create(execution_time: scheduled_time, lists: "lists", message_id: @message.id, user_id: current_user.id)` the stored value is the database is `"--- \n- \"58\"\n- \"\"\n"` and when `Schedule.create(execution_time: scheduled_time, lists: "#{lists}", message_id: @message.id, user_id: current_user.id)` then the stored value is like this `"[\"34\", \"\"]"` Yet the desired value is `["34", ""]`.

The controller method is as below;

```
def create
  @lists = current_user.lists.all
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  lists = params[:message][:lists]
  schedule = params[:message][:schedule]

  if @message.save
    if schedule.blank?
      MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, lists, current_user.id)
    else
      scheduled_time = DateTime.strptime(schedule,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z").to_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      Schedule.create(execution_time: scheduled_time, lists: "#{lists}", message_id: @message.id, user_id: current_user.id)
    end
    redirect_to new_message_path, notice: 'Message was successfully added to the queue.'

  else
    render action: "new"
    flash[:notice] = "Messages Not Sent"
end
```

Why are there added slashes in the stored value?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are no added slashes. Instead, you have a string with quote character `"`, and Ruby will escape that for you as `\"` when you e.g.  use `.inspect` to check its value on a terminal

Comment: What does the model look like? Seems that you're trying to stick an array into a string column and Rails is converting the array to YAML behind your back.

Comment: @NeilSlater, how do you suggest i should store an array in the database because the value passed is an array.

Comment: @muistooshort, yes it an array in a string value. I am asking how should i store it?

Comment: Are you using `serialize` in the model? What does the model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes are being added to escape the quote characters. This is normal when taking an array and making it a string, which is what is going on behind the scenes. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats) for more info about escape characters.

If you really want to store several values in one field (consider storing in separate table which can then be `JOIN`'d to) then either store them in JSON format, or as comma separated values. Both approaches require that you parse the value stored when reading it out from the database.

JSON:

```
lists = JSON.generate(params[:message][:lists]) # an array such as ["1", "2"], converted to JSON format
=> "[\"1\",\"2\"]" # it's a string, with quotes escapted. Store this in the database.

# then you can parse it to make it an array again
JSON.parse(lists)
=> ["1", "2"]
```

Comma separated values:

```
lists = params[:message][:lists].join(",") # assuming params[:message][:lists] is an array
=> "1,2" # A string with each value from the array separated by a comma. Store this in database

# then when you read that value from database
lists.split(",")
=> ["1", "2"] # back in array format
```

You are taking an array, and then storing it as a string. When converted to this format, the slashes are required. To get your string back into array format, you need to parse the string - this will 'remove' the slashes. Make sure you understand the difference between `["1", "2"]` and `"[\"1\", \"2\"]"`